# Django: update two models at once

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two Django models like so:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class UserSkills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % (self.user, self.skill)
```

Now, I have lists of skills associated with a user which I want to simultaneously update the Skills model and the User's associated skills. Something like:

```
# cleaned_skills[] is list if unicode strings

for skill in cleaned_skills:
    s, created = Skill.objects.get_or_create(title=skill)
    s.save()
    u, created = UserSkills.objects.get_or_create(skill=s, user=request.user)
    u.save()
```

For some reason this doesn't feel right to me. Is there some way I should update both the `Skill` and the `User` models at the same time?

Comment: you should consider using a `post_save` signal on `Skill` model to create a `UserSkills` object

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, though I do admit I'm not very familiar with signals.

Comment: There is a lot of help available. Especially on SO. You should be fine

Comment: Thanks. I'll check into it.

Comment: And calling `save` isn't necessary for the `get_or_create` method. We you call it, if the object isn't in the database, [it creates it on fly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L451).

Comment: oh, so `s, created = Skill.objects.get_or_create(title=skill)` will create the object if doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes. You're correct :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by the `post_save signal`. How do I pass the `Skill` object to the `User`. Do I just assume it was the last one which was saved? What happens if that `Skill` doesn't get saved because it exists, but I need to save it to the user's skills?

Comment: I am still finding it difficult to resolve this, especially getting the request.user in the receiver. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think you're doing it correctly.

Comment: You, mean do it in the view?

Comment: @DarwinTech Yes. If you're doing it repeatedly across multiple views, I would put the code in the Manager. Have a look at http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html#adding-extra-manager-methods and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/ .